# What is the process for the community to propose an XLM lockup?

Tags: xlm, stellar-core, xrp, ripple

Let me start by saying I am not proposing a wholesale token "burning" as I believe that could have unintended negative consequences long term.

However, considering the tremendous price appreciation in 2017 and attendant price volatility in 2017, what process is available to the community to propose an escrow plan for a percentage of the XLM still held by SDF?

Ripple did this with XRP a few months ago (https://www.coindesk.com/ripple-pledges-lock-14-billion-xrp-cryptocurrency/)and even if one could argue it practically does little, it does send a strong and powerful signal both to the Stellar community as well as the broader public.

Comment: I don't believe there is an actual process for this. Your best bet would probably be to bring it up in slack.

Answer (score 0):

Given that this is mostly a technical forum, I think your question would be better asked in [Stellar's Keybase](https://keybase.io/team/stellar.public).

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is from 2018, the community cannot decide on what the SDF does with the XLM they hold. However, the SDF clearly has it in the community's interest so after years and months of requesting more transparency the SDF released a new mandate which outlines 3 Billion XLM being escrowed per year until 2023.

https://www.stellar.org/foundation/mandate

They are other methods the SDF wants to use XLM over the next couple years, such as Ecosystem support, Enterprise fund, and User acquisition.

It can all be tracked live here:

https://www.stellar.org/foundation/mandate#total